# Frobenius method applied to $x^2y''+(x^2-x)y'+2y=0$

Tags: frobenius-method

Using Frobenius method for solving the ODE

$$x^2y''+(x^2-x)y'+2y=0$$

I am getting roots of inicial equation as $1 + i$ and $1 - i$ so I am not getting to solve when the roots are complex.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The method works just as well for complex roots as for real ones, you just have to do arithmetic using complex numbers.  You might note that
$$ x^{a + b i} = x^a x^{bi} = x^a \exp(b i \ln(x)) = x^a (\cos(b \ln(x)) + i \sin(b \ln(x))$$